# How i can replace "legend" word of a chart in Angular ngx-charts?

Tags: angular, angular8, ngx-charts

I am using ngx-charts in my Angular 8 app. I have display a "Grouped Vertical Bar Chart", this one have a section with a label what i want to translate to spanish; it says "Legend", i want to replace it by "Leyenda", but i dont know how, because the library does not have a particular option to change that text. How i can do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

referring to this [documentation](https://swimlane.gitbook.io/ngx-charts/examples/bar-charts/grouped-vertical-bar-chart) there's a property named legendTitle, you can change this property to achieve your goal.